# how to send xml file to server backend using php?

Tags: php, xml, curl, xmlhttprequest

I have fetched data from server using this code, `$server = 'LOCALHOST:9000';

```
$headers = array(
"Content-type: text/xml"
,"Content-length: ".strlen($requestXML)
,"Connection: close"
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);



if(curl_errno($ch)){
    print curl_error($ch);
    echo "  something went wrong..... try later";
}else{
echo " request accepted";
    print $data;
    curl_close($ch);
}`
```

Now I have to do reverse, how to send the data into server using php? curl method is the only way or is there any other method to do the same. Give me some example.

Comment: Sending and receiving data is exactly the same in cURL. Because when you are getting data from a server, you are sending a request at first. The only difference is the data being send and being received..

Comment: so if it is same then what short of changes i have to do? because i google it and getting the same thing which you share and i tried the same but not getting the desired output what i want, so if you used the same then can you suggest what short of changes do i required for achieving appropriate result?

Comment: See my answer in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Sending/Receiving using cURL is the exact same thing. cURL is based on sending data to an given URL and possibly receiving a response. Let's take a simple example of getting a user and sending a user.

**Getting a user would be**

```
$data = array(
  'user_id' => 1
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/getUser.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

- getUser.php does nothing more than search for a user and return the data found.
- $response would possibly contain data of the user, perhaps just a text-response containing the name. A serialized PHP array, an XML response with a full user profile.. etc.

**Inserting/Sending data**

```
$data = array(
  'user_name' => 'Joshua',
  'user_email' => 'my@email.com'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/addUser.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

- addUser.php performs some validation of the fields and if validated inserts a user in the database
- $response in this case does not contain the userdata (however: it's a possibility), but more likely the $response contains a result. An `ok` textresponse, a json/xml response or perhaps a '200 OK' header response

It's all basically the same. There is no difference in getting/sending data using cURL. It's all based on sending a request and in most cases do something with the outcome.

Comment: The way you explained me my problem it seems that the code i used for fetching the data is used for inserting the data as well but print portion which i have to display will going to be change.

Comment: exactly :) anything you need explained?

Comment: i understand the concept but i am still facing the problem but that is because of the server which i am using, my method and approach is correct..
BTW thank you for solving my doughs.. :)